# EE File management

Tags: css

EE file management questioned corrected.  Please close.

Comment: This isn't really a question, so much as a request for someone to create something. Additionally, it'd be very difficult to create a boilerplate for EE, since the template structure is custom to every site. It wouldn't vary at all from a static site boilerplate.

Comment: The WP git is NOT a theme at all.  It is best practices for structuring SASS and COMPASS >> any CSS.  i've been using EE since 1.5.2 and am very familiar with all the commercial EE "themes" including woo but never used them .  We developed all themes at that time in-house.

Comment: I was not asking for "free work'  from a developer.  This WP link to a SASS and COMPASS best practices on git was volunteered by the developer in response to a similar question on a WP blog. Best practices is a legitimate question for the EE community.

Comment: Jeremy is right, as it currently stands this isn't a question. If you want to ask how to set up Compass and SCSS with EE then you should write that. Once you edit the question people will be able to answer it.

Comment: Hey Chris - can you elaborate on what kinds of CSS pre-processor practices you might expect would be unique to EE as  CMS? EE never generates any HTML on your behalf, you write it all yourself, so I can't see anything about EE dictating different best practices personally.

Comment: I have included in my question above ONE example of how the type of CSS preprocessor and related functions can be included in EE specific file architecture, to provide the clarity that the commenters have requested.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a hypothetical question, as Jeremy states, although it's possible it's not really worth the effort due to the many, many approaches. There's one developer I know of who has created "themes" that used to be sold through [Theme Forest](http://themeforest.net) (but now no longer available), you can see them [here](http://themes.bybjorn.com). [Woothemes](http://www.woothemes.com/2010/01/welcome-to-weethemes/) attempted it as well [(examples)](http://dzineblog.com/2011/02/10-best-expressionengine-themes-by-woothemes.html), but again they discontinued them and they're [no longer available](http://www.woothemes.com/2011/04/re-focusing/).

The point is, "theming" doesn't work in EE because of the different approaches to site structure, templates (naming, URLs, code, etc) and due to the amount of commercial add-ons (and variations in those) that are mostly standard to all EE builds.

Look at the default "theme" that comes with EE - it's meant as an example build to learn from, not to use in the real world or to expand upon.

There could be an approach whereby a module was developed to force rigid template usage for a build (e.g. like Wordpress has fixed templates for key functions), but ExpressionEngine's main strength is it's flexibility and freedom in approach and development.

More info on [EE Insider](http://eeinsider.com/blog/ellislab-ceo-on-ee-growth-and-challenges/)